# Python GUI writing to a file

Tags: python, user-interface

I am have a problem trying to get this function to work properly. I need it to write to a text file that includes "First Name: " , then add the input from the entry field at the end of "First Name: ".

```
def _NameEntry(self):
        open("Results.txt", "w").close()
        first = self._firstNameEntry.get()
        with open("../Results.txt", "a") as the_file:
            the_file.write("First Name: ", + first)
```

But when I use this function it errors this:

> "the_file.write("First Name: ", + first) TypeError: bad operand type
>   for unary +: 'str'"

If I get rid of the `("First Name: ", +)`, then it will write the entry field to the text file, whatever the value is.

Comment: `,` indicates the separation of arguments and then the lone `+` is interpreted as a unary operator.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi...Thanks for the explanation...I was trying to relate the traceback message to the actual error...but got confused..:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your Syntax. 
It should be:

```
the_file.write("First Name: " + first)
```

Comment: I see. I thought it was something small. That darn comma gets me a lot. lol. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why `str(first)` ??...`entry.get()` should return a string

Comment: @IronFist I'm accustomed to doing that. But well noticed